Boolean Modifier Not Working
I have this quite complex 3d model (I didn't make it: https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/art/dragon-jeje817) and I am trying to split it down the middle with the Boolean modifier and I have tried to bisect it but that makes it hollow and I can't have it be hollow. When I use the modifier and offset the cube to cut a third off it works fine but when I put it in the middle it doesn't work: 
I was wondering if anyone knew how to make it work.

hello, if t is copyright free could you please share the object?

It isn't but you can click the link and download it.

Downloading the original model will not show us how you have set up your scene objects and the Boolean modifier to achieve your goal.

@MarkBlasi Note that your meshes have to be manifold for the boolean operations to work as expected. Without it, no guarantee it will work. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry

As a general rule I agree with the comments that giving us your .blend is going to lead to better problem solving.
Still, I was able to replicate your error by downloading the .STL.  It would not boolean.
For whatever reason, applying CTRL + A 'all transforms' to the imported .STL model worked for me. Also Boolean 'fast' seemed to yield better results than 'exact'.
Still, even though a face was successfully created by the boolean it is not smooth.   It may require a little retopology as the comments suggest because there are interior faces.  You should probably ask another question about this if it is unclear.


